# APIM named value create or update rest api is not working

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-api-management

I am using REST  [create or update rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/named-value/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP) to create the APIM named value in my PowerShell script

script:

```
 $requestPayload = @{
    properties = @{
        displayName = $displayname
        keyVault = @{
            secretIdentifier = $SecretIdentifier 
        }
        secret = $true
    }
}

 # Convert the hash table to a JSON string
            $jsonPayload = $requestPayload | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5

            # Create/Update named values

            
            $baseurl="https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/";
    
            $headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer " + $accesstoken  }$url=$baseurl+$SubscriptionId+"/resourceGroups/"+$ResourceGroupName+"/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/"+$APIMResourceName+"/namedValues/$($Name)?api-version=2022-08-01";
        
            $result=Invoke-WebRequest  $url -Method 'Put' -Headers $headers  -Body  $jsonPayload -ContentType "application/json" -UseBasicParsing
 Write-Output( $result)
```

This script works perfectly fine in 3 of my environments(lab and test in pre prod subscription and prv in prod subscription) but in prod environment it is not working.

The output $result in all 4 environment is same that is Response code 202 accepted. Except production environment the named value is getting created properly with keyvault secret reference, only in prod it is not working. I was not able to find out the actual cause as this api is returning the 202 accepted response.  In APIM service also I checked activity log there also I can see the accepted and started logs but not succeeded or completed or any error log.

Without knowing the error details it is hard to solve this issue.

I have also verified that apim instance, it has get and list access policy set in keyvault.

Please let me know is there way to find out what is the error.

Comment: This is kind of a bug from Microsoft. If for any reason API request fails. At least we should be able to find the reason in the APIM service activity logs. Activity logs on shows the Accepted log. nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

202 response should come with Location header pointing at URL where you can monitor the process. Poll on that with GET request untill you get anything else but 202 and that response should contain error information.

If I would have to guess, your APIM service in prod does not have access to a KeyVault you're creating Named Value for. Make sure APIM service has Managed Identity enabled. If your KeyVault is configured in Access Policy, make sure prod APIM service's identity is addedd to ACL to read secret value. IF your KeyVault is in RBAC mode, make sure APIM service is added at least Secret User role in Access Control.

Comment: In my case I noticed that NSG Outbound rule added to deny virtual network to internet traffic. this rule was there in only prod environment so after allowing traffic to internet it worked.

Comment: This solved my issue, I had an APIM instance that is shared across environments. In my Terraform templates I had assigned the APIM instance the Key Vault Secrets User role for the UAT Key Vault, but not for the PROD Key Vault, so when I tried to create the named values, I was getting a 404 error. Interestingly, when debugging the issue by using the Azure Management REST API directly, without the role assignment a 202 response would still be returned but the named value wouldn't be created. Adding the role assignment resulted in a 202 response with the named value being created.